# Short and simple question related to Fubini's theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm trying to understand what should be a fairly simple portion of a proof of Problem 2.5.4 of the Stein/Shakarchi Real Analysis textbook.

Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on $[0,b]$. Then for the purposes of integration, we can assume that $f$ is non-negative.

(Sorry my $\chi$'s are coming out very small, not sure how to fix this latex issue).

Then

$$\begin{align}
\tag{1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{t} \Large\chi_{(x,b]}(t) \chi_{[0,b]}(x)dt ~dx
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{t} \Large\chi_{[0,b]}(x)dx \right) \Large\chi_{(x,b]}(t)dt \\
\tag{2*}&= \int_0^b \left( \int_0^t \frac{f(t)}{t}dx \right)dt
\end{align}$$

Where (1) follows from Fubini's thereom.

But I don't understand the move to (2*) -- specifically why we get $\int_0^t$ on the inside, rather than $\int_0^b$ coming from the $\chi_{[0,b]}$, but then I'm also not making sense of how $\Large\chi_{(x,b]}$ affects the interval of integration on the outside.

I know I'm missing something elementary here.

Comment: The two indicator functions mean you are integrating over the region $0 \le x \le b$ and $x < t \le b$.  The $\chi_{(x,b]}(t)$ means $x < t$, so when you integrate over $x$ first you get $t$ as the upper limit of integration.  I agree that it's confusing having $\chi_{(x,b]}(t)$ on the outside of the $dx$ integral, though.

Comment: Do, between dollar signs, \Large\chi\ , and you'll get $\;\Large\chi\;$ instead of $\chi\;$ .

Comment: It will be clearer if you write it as
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{f(t)}{t}I(x < t \leq b)I(0 \leq x \leq b)\,dt\,dx$$ and apply Tonelli's theorem from here.

Comment: I think the small chi's are correct.  They should align with letters like gpqy, as here: $g\chi y\chi$.  See also gamma eta ... $\chi\gamma\eta$

Comment: Thanks all, the result is now clear to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not in deriving (2) from (1). The problem is that (1) is wrong. They made a mistake when they wrote it out. $x$ is a dummy variable of the inside integration, yet is referenced outside that integration, where it is undefined. The RH side of (1) does not make sense.

What they are actually depending on is this
$$\large{\chi}_{(x,b]}(t)\large{\chi}_{[0,b]}(x) = \large{\chi}_{[0,b]}(t)\large{\chi}_{[0,t)}(x)$$
Which follows because both expressions are $1$ if and only if $0 \le x < t \le b$. Otherwise they are both $0$.
What they should have written is
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{f(t)}t{\large\chi}_{(x,b]}(t){\large\chi}_{[0,b]}(x)~dt~dx
&=\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{f(t)}t{\large\chi}_{[0,b]}(t){\large\chi}_{[0,t)}(x)~dt~dx\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R} \left( \int_{\Bbb R} \frac{f(t)}{t} {\large\chi}_{[0,t)}(x)~dx \right) {\large\chi}_{[0,b]}(t)~dt \\
&= \int_0^b \left( \int_0^t \frac{f(t)}{t}~dx \right)~dt
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in that first equality! The commentors also noted that my (1) was fairly confusing.